# What happens when a scheduled task didn't finish before next scheduled time starts?

Tags: elasticsearch, cron, logstash, scheduled-tasks

Using `Logstash` to import data from `Mysql` to `Elasticsearch`, the sql track the `update_timestamp` of a table, and scheduled every **1 minutes**.

There are some special cases when the sql can't finish in 1 minute *(e.g initial import into a new ES instance)*.

BTW, it seems that logstash will do import in small batches of 100k rows if the sql matches over 100k rows.

**The question is:**

- If the sql can't finish in 1 minutes *(aka. before next scheduled time starts)*, what will logstash do?

  Will it:

  - Skip the next scheduled task?
    This seems to be the case, in my observation, but not sure.
  - Delay the next scheduled task, but never skip one?
  - Or, something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jdbc input [sets](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/blob/0cee881dcdae5ba75716dacab54aba8da13086b6/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb#L274) max_work_threads for the [Rufus scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) to one. If there is no available worker thread then [trigger_queue](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/a684facba5202d09007e2ed3513b4a1038869ee6/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb#L345) does nothing, so that instance of the job will never be run. It will wait until the next time the queue should be triggered.

Comment: So, it will skip the task once.